# Catch exception from toplevel

Tags: ruby, exception

This is probably a very simple question but I can't seem to find the answer for it anywhere. I'm new to Ruby 1.9 and use it to write short scripts.

My question is how do I handle Exceptions at the toplevel in a file? Is it really necessary to wrap the section which might throw an exception in a begin/end clause?

Essentially what I'm trying to do is this:

```
File.open( "foo" )
rescue Errno::EACCES => e
    # Handle exception
```

Comment: are you going to do something useful in the exception handling? if not, in simple scripts is ok just to let it blow up.

Comment: It's part of a loop which is collecting data from a serial connection. I thought my problem was the serial port but actually it was the File.open command would fail on occation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.open is not doing anything magical, essentially it's just File.new with a block wrapped into begin/ensure, which will close the file automatically for you at the end of the block, no matter if the block ended normally, or if some exception occured inside it.

So you should handle exceptions in the case of File.open like in any other parts of your ruby code.
You can let it slide and let exceptions be handled elsewhere (by other handlers in exception handlers chain), or you can be strict and handle them on the spot. This decision has nothing to do with File.open, it has more to do with the nature of your code/app and target audience. For example, if you are writing a script which will only be run by you, it's probably fine to let the exception slide and crash the script with a stack trace, in other cases you'd probably want to be more "professional" and handle it gracefully, in which case you'd have to use begin/rescue at some point.

Here's the code which hopefully would demystify File.open (it's basically just an implementation of [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) in Ruby)

```
File.open("foo") {|f|
  # do something with the opened file
  f.read

  # once the block has finished, the file will be closed automatically
}

# File.open is essentially:
f = File.new "foo"
begin
  yield f
ensure
  f.close
end

# So in any case if you'd like to handle any exception that might be raised, just do the usual thing:
begin
  File.open("foo") {|f|
    # do something with the opened file
    f.read
  }
rescue
  # handle all the exceptions - either coming from open/new or from inner file-handling block
end

begin
  f = File.new "foo"
  begin
    # do something with the opened file
    f.read
  ensure
    f.close
  end
rescue
  # handle the exceptions, using multiple rescue if needed to catch exact exception types like Errno::EACCES, etc
end
```

Comment: Demystification accomplished :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rescuing the exception, in this case you might want to check for the existence before opening the file.

```
if File.exist?("foo.txt")
  File.open("foo.txt")
else
  abort("file.txt doesn't exist")
end
```

Comment: Yes - exceptions are for *exceptional* events. If you expect the file to not be there on occasions, code for the eventuality.

Comment: This seems to be a case of an obvious answer completely eluding me. Thank you.